# Creating Athena table via glue crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have an s3 bucket that contains json data in the following format:

```
{
  a :foo,
  b: bar
 
}
{
  a :foo,
  b: bar 
}
```

I have a firehose which outputs data to s3. here is the following s3 configuration:

```
  extended_s3_configuration {
    bucket_arn         = aws_s3_bucket.destination_bucket.arn
    role_arn           = aws_iam_role.firehose.arn
    compression_format = "GZIP"
    buffer_interval    = 600 // this in seconds
    buffer_size        = 128 // this is in MB

    cloudwatch_logging_options {
      enabled         = true
      log_group_name  = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.firehose_logs.name
      log_stream_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_stream.firehose_log_stream.name
    }

    dynamic_partitioning_configuration {
      enabled = "true"
    }
    prefix              = "data/clientType=!{partitionKeyFromQuery:clientType}/date=!{timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd}/"
    error_output_prefix = "errors/date=!{timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd}/!{firehose:error-output-type}"

    processing_configuration {
      enabled = "true"
      processors {
        type = "RecordDeAggregation"
        parameters {
          parameter_name  = "SubRecordType"
          parameter_value = "JSON"
        }
      }

      processors {
        type = "MetadataExtraction"
        parameters {
          parameter_name  = "JsonParsingEngine"
          parameter_value = "JQ-1.6"
        }
        parameters {
          parameter_name  = "MetadataExtractionQuery"
          parameter_value = "{clientType:.clientType}"
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

Now I have setup a crawler that crawls the bucket containing above data and create athena tables out of it. When I query athena table, I see only one record in the table however above data contains 2 records. I couldn't find any information that athena only shows unique records as my data is duplicated. Any ideas what might be happening ?